# Use custom SASS style sheets among multiple projects with Gulp

Tags: css, sass, rubygems, gulp, compass

I am using Gulp and Scss. I have my own folder of custom sass stylesheets. At the moment, I copy them to each project folder, which makes them a nightmare to maintain and update.

Is there any way I can put them in a global location and then use them in every project with Gulp.

This was possible in CodeKit, but I'm not sure how to do it in Gulp.

---

### Steps I have tried

1. Creating a Compass extension
   http://compass-style.org/help/tutorials/extensions/

I've tried this. However, I am not sure how the files in the project folder link back to the stylesheet folder. Also, I'm not sure where I should put my extension to make it available everywhere.

2. Creating a Gem
   I took the gem for CSS-Lightbox, copied and then replaced it with my own files. I'm not sure how to use it with gulp. It also has the same issues with (1) above.

Isn't there a programme that can just take my folder of SASS sheets and then turn it into a plugin I can use with Gulp? thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to achieve what you want. I'll summarize just one.

1. Make a private npm package. The structure could be as simple as

   ```
   |
   |- package.json
   |- sass/
   ```
2. Add your stylesheets to this package.

   ```
   |
   |- package.json
   |- sass/
      |
      |- file1.scss
      |- file2.scss
   ```
3. Link to this local package from within each of your projects' `package.json`
4. Read the options for the gulp/sass package you're using; one will explain how to add include paths.
5. Add `node_modules/your-private-package-name/sass/`

If you're going to go down this path, regardless of the solution, you should really be versioning your Sass files in such a way that you can lock each of your projects against specific tags/versions. It will otherwise be likely to cause you headaches down the road when you go to rebuild an old project after making a small change and months worth of changes to these common Sass files suddenly wreaks havoc on your project.